# No need to manually check Google Play Services version anymore?

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderclient

It's been a while since I worked with Google Play Services and I'm now implementing a feature that requires location tracking. After following a dated example that used `GoogleApiClient`, I found this post about the new Location APIs at Android Developers blog:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html

```
FusedLocationProviderClient client =
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

client.requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest.create(), pendingIntent)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Result: " + task.getResult());
      }
    });
}
```

What caught my attention was something written at the bottom of the post, saying:

> The new API will automatically resolve certain connection failures for
>   you, **so you don't need to write code that for things like prompting
>   the user to update Google Play services**.

Since I've already written that piece of code  using `GoogleApiAvailabilty` I'm curious if it's safe to just remove it and let the `FusedLocationProviderClient` take care of it?

I've tried to find another source to verify this but failed, not really satisfied with half a line at the bottom of a blog post, hence posting the question here.

Comment: *I'm curious if it's safe to just remove it* - well they added that note for a reason..

Comment: Yeah but I haven't been able to verify it in any actual documentation, it's just half a line in a blog post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I'll answer my own question after a quick test. I temporarily removed the checks that made sure Google Play Services was available and the correct version. Then installed the app on an emulator without Google Play Services and when I try to use the `LocationServices API` I get a sticky headsup notification saying:

> [app name] won't run unless you update Google Play Services.

So I guess it's safe to remove the checks.

Worth noting is that it seems the listeners (Success/Failure/Complete) are not called unless the user actually interacts with the notification, if they for example just press something else in your apps UI, the listeners were not called.